# AngularJS : How to concat two arrays?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following arrays with values (i am generating the values on go)

```
$scope.objectName = [{ Name: '' }];
$scope.propertiesElement = [{ Key: '', Value: '' }];
```

I want to concatenate these two objects to get the following result

```
[{Name:''},{ Key: '', Value: '' }]
```

Plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/67xxL7yQv88wMYZSvwhY?p=preview) , somehow that's not working either

when I click on the add row button it will add another row for key and value text boxes only not for name, I can add n no of rows and when I click on Submit it should show the kev value pair as

```
[{Name:''},{ Key: '', Value: '' },{ Key: '', Value: '' },{ Key: '', Value: '' }.....so on]
```

Thanks

Comment: Uh.... why do you want the name in the same array as your key value pairs. Couldn't you submit it like this:

    var submission = {};
    submission.name = $scope.objecName.name;
    submission.keyValuePairs = $scope.propertiesElement;

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to build an array of mismatched objects.  That seems to me to be asking for trouble.  I would suggest possibly doing the following:

```
$scope.objects = [{Name: '', Elements: []}];
```

Then you can easily manage multiple objects who have elements:

(I use underscore http://underscorejs.org/)

```
$scope.addElementToObject = function(objName, element){
   _.where($scope.mergedArray, {Name: objName}).Elements.push(element);
};
```

Then you can add to the list of elements for that object without having to eval the object in the elements array on each use.

---

If you still want/need to merge arrays of mismatched objects, it would be the following:

```
$scope.objectName = [{ Name: '' }];
$scope.propertiesElement = [{ Key: '', Value: '' }];
$scope.mergedArray = $scope.objectName.contact($scope.propertiesElement);

$scope.addElement = function(element){
   $scope.mergedArray.push(element);
};
```

Then, in your click event code:

```
$scope.addElement({ Key: 'someKey', Value: 'Some Value' });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Still my early days with AngularJs, so have to post questions like this to get acquainted with it .. I did the change that Mike suggested, and it worked
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Actually, this wasn't really an Angular question. It's more of a pure javascript question.  There's nothing strictly Angularly about my solution (or Mike's). It's all just knowing how ECMA 5 Script (javascript) works. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript